# Error inflating TextView in Samsung phones

Tags: android, android-layout

```
2021-08-31 12:32:52.374 20003-20003/develup.solutions.greenpatio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: develup.solutions.greenpatio, PID: 20003
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{develup.solutions.greenpatio/develup.solutions.teva.activities.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in develup.solutions.greenpatio:layout/emailsplashlayout: Binary XML file line #8 in develup.solutions.greenpatio:layout/emailsplashlayout: Error inflating class TextView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3995)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2309)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8587)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in develup.solutions.greenpatio:layout/emailsplashlayout: Binary XML file line #8 in develup.solutions.greenpatio:layout/emailsplashlayout: Error inflating class TextView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in develup.solutions.greenpatio:layout/emailsplashlayout: Error inflating class TextView
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=0 out of bounds (limit=0, nb=4)
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:564)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.getInt(DirectByteBuffer.java:570)
    at android.graphics.fonts.FontFileUtil.analyzeStyle(FontFileUtil.java:94)
    at android.graphics.fonts.Font$Builder.build(Font.java:407)
    at android.graphics.Typeface$Builder.build(Typeface.java:692)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadFont(ResourcesImpl.java:1214)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getFont(Resources.java:545)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getFont(TypedArray.java:1036)
    at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:4357)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1360)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1241)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:99)
    at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.<init>(MaterialTextView.java:91)
    at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.<init>(MaterialTextView.java:86)
    at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.<init>(MaterialTextView.java:81)
    at com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater.createTextView(MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java:109)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1059)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
2021-08-31 12:32:52.375 20003-20003/develup.solutions.greenpatio E/AndroidRuntime:     at develup.solutions.teva.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:79)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3995)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2309)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8587)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

And the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:text="@string/introducemail"
    android:id="@+id/introducemail"
    android:textColor="@color/frontcolor"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tilm"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/introducemail"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColorHint="@color/black"
    app:hintEnabled="false">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etlogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext_white"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/frontcolor"
        android:alpha=".8"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tilm"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:alpha="0.2"
    android:background="@color/frontcolor"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/frontcolor"
    android:text="@string/seeevents"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/gplogo"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
```

It works perfectly in almost all phones...tried in a couple of Samsung phones and the app crashes. Any help?

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=0 out of bounds (limit=0, nb=4)` the real problem is here

Comment: are you trying to access position of words or something like that? show your code as well

Comment: I'm not doing something like that. I'm just showing a text from strings.xml

Comment: [Here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/fonts/FontFileUtil.java;drc=a1c21c0a022f0d47cbda40929e5c2eaf78c48f0c;l=94) is where your app is crashing. Are you doing anything with fonts? Maybe one that is not available on Samsung?

Comment: Actually, I have a default font in my app. Removed that font and now its not crashing. So there is the mistake. Is there any list of fonts not available to Samsung?

Comment: You need to tag me to get the message to me. I just happened to see this. I don't know of such a list or if what I mentioned is even the root problem.  Now that you know that the issue is related to fonts, you could do a search to see if someone else has discovered the problem and found a fix.